# Error in Super keyword in ArrayAdapter in kotlin

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin, super

I was trying to send the word ArrayList in other ArrayDapter class, but the error arises that it has too many arguments and super keyword in kotlin can only be used on the left side of "." operator.

```
    package com.example.android.miwok

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView


class NumbersActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers)

    val words = ArrayList<Word>()
    words.add(Word("one","lutti"))
    words.add( Word("two", "otiiko"));
    words.add( Word("three", "tolookosu"));
    words.add( Word("four", "oyyisa"));
    words.add( Word("five", "massokka"));
    words.add( Word("six", "temmokka"));
    words.add( Word("seven", "kenekaku"));
    words.add( Word("eight", "kawinta"));
    words.add( Word("nine", "wo’e"));
    words.add( Word("ten", "na’aacha"));

    val adapter = WordAdapter(this,words)

    val listView = findViewById(R.id.list) as ListView?

    listView!!.setAdapter(adapter)
    }
}
```

The WordAdapter.kt file:-

```
package com.example.android.miwok

    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
    import android.app.Activity
    import android.content.Context
    import android.widget.TextView
    import android.view.LayoutInflater


    class WordAdapter : ArrayAdapter<Word>() {

        fun WordAdapter(context: Activity, words: ArrayList<Word>){
            super.ArrayAdapter<Word>(context, 0, words)
        }

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            var listItemView = convertView
            if (listItemView == null) {
                listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
            }

            val currentWord = getItem(position)

            val nameTextView = listItemView!!.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view) as TextView

            nameTextView.setText(currentWord!!.getDefaultTranslation())

            val numberTextView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view) as TextView

            numberTextView.setText(currentWord!!.getMiwokTranslation())

            return listItemView
        }
    }
```

I am not able to find the error in this.

The word super should be linked to which part is also confusable to me.

Comment: Why are you calling `super.ArrayAdapter`? Just use `ArrayAdapter` directly

Comment: @Zoe, he wants to show more than one view per row.

Comment: @AndreArtus so? Just initializing as `ArrayAdapter` is more than enough

Comment: @Zoe, would you mind putting up an example? By default ArrayAdapter only loads one TextView (in a ViewGroup).

Comment: The point being `super.ArrayAdapter<...>....` can be replaced with `ArrayAdapter<...>...`. As in removing the `super.` part. That's all there is to it

Comment: @Zoe, I see now what you mean, but it won't make his code work. It would be broken in one more way.

Comment: @AndreArtus It seemed like the most obvious mistake. Imo, this should be closed (No MCVE; there's no error log/stacktrace)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183426/discussion-between-andre-artus-and-zoe).

Comment: @Priyanshu Vaya, there is some issues with the clarity of your question.  Would you like some assistance in restating it? Otherwise it is likely to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can improve upon:

You are currently writing Javlin, or Kotva, i.e. a mix of Java and Kotlin.

You should not be inflating the layout for every getView, and you should ideally be using the ViewHolder pattern (now shown below).

But the reason for your question, the compiler error calling `super`. You are defining your constructor as a function, not a constructor.

In Java constructors are defined by writing methods with the same name as the class. In Kotlin you just pass the constructor parameters in the class definition. e.g.

```
class WordAdapter(context: Context, objects: List<Word>)
```

and pass those parameters through to the extended class as such:

```
class WordAdapter(context: Context, objects: List<Word>) :
    ArrayAdapter<Word>(context, R.layout.list_item, R.id.default_text_view, objects)
```

an alternative approach, usually reserved for secondary constructors:

```
class WordAdapter : ArrayAdapter<Word> {  
    constructor(context: Context, objects: List<Word>) : super(
        context, R.layout.list_item, R.id.default_text_view, objects
    )
}
```

Here is a somewhat Kotlinified version of your code (I saw that you were swapping default and miwok in your getView, I assumed that was a mistake and did not copy that). [I've also put a copy up on Github](https://github.com/andre-artus/ExtendArrayAdapter).

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val words = arrayListOf(
        Word("one", "lutti"),
        Word("two", "otiiko"),
        Word("three", "tolookosu"),
        Word("four", "oyyisa"),
        Word("five", "massokka"),
        Word("six", "temmokka"),
        Word("seven", "kenekaku"),
        Word("eight", "kawinta"),
        Word("nine", "wo’e"),
        Word("ten", "na’aacha")
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list)
        val adapter = WordAdapter(this, words)

        listView.adapter = adapter
    }
}

data class Word(val defaultTranslation: String, val miwokTranslation: String)

class WordAdapter(context: Context, objects: List<Word>) :
    ArrayAdapter<Word>(context, R.layout.list_item, R.id.default_text_view, objects) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val listItemView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
        val defaultTextView = listItemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.default_text_view)
        val miwokTextView = listItemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.miwok_text_view)

        getItem(position)?.run {
            defaultTextView.text = defaultTranslation
            miwokTextView.text = miwokTranslation
        }
        return listItemView
    }
}
```

Here is an example adapter using (a version of) the ViewHolder pattern (if you put a logging breakpoint on any of the `row.findViewById`s you will see they are only called for as many items as are being displayed, not for every item in the list):

```
class WordAdapter(context: Context, objects: List<Word>) :
    ArrayAdapter<Word>(context, R.layout.list_item, R.id.default_text_view, objects) {

    class ViewHolder(row: View) {
        init {
            row.tag = this
        }

        val defaultTextView = row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.default_text_view)!!
        val miwokTextView = row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.miwok_text_view)!!
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val listItemView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)

        val holder = listItemView.tag as? ViewHolder ?: ViewHolder(listItemView)

        getItem(position)?.run {
            holder.defaultTextView.text = defaultTranslation
            holder.miwokTextView.text = miwokTranslation
        }

        return listItemView
    }
}
```

If you want to go overboard [:)] with Kotlin idioms:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View =
    super.getView(position, convertView, parent).also { row ->
        (row.tag as? ViewHolder ?: ViewHolder(row)).apply {
            getItem(position)?.run {
                defaultTextView.text = defaultTranslation
                miwokTextView.text = miwokTranslation
            }
        }
    }
```